# DocBook 5: How do I do variable substitution to replace ${version} by a value?

Tags: xml, xsd, docbook, docbook-5

While writing a large manual in DocBook 5 (which uses an XSD, not DTD), I need to mention the version name in many places. For example, the name of distribution zip includes the version name. That version name changes constantly, so I 'd like to use a variable for that.

How do I do variable substitution in DocBook 5 (which uses an XSD, not DTD)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An [XML entity](http://www.w3.org/TR/xml/#sec-internal-ent) is a kind of macro or substitutable variable, so I suggest that you use one or more of those. Entities can be declared and referenced in any XML document, even if a DTD is not used for validation.

Declaration of the `version` entity (an internal entity):

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE book [
<!ENTITY version "Version X">
]>
<book xmlns="http://docbook.org/ns/docbook" version="5.0">
 ...
</book>
```

Reference to the `version` entity:

```
<book xmlns="http://docbook.org/ns/docbook" version="5.0">
 ...
 <para>The current version is &version;</para>
</book>
```

When the document is parsed, the parser replaces all occurrences of `&version;` with `Version X`.

There are more details and suggestions here: http://www.sagehill.net/docbookxsl/Db5Entities.html.